# Anylogic stop delay when the node is empty

Tags: anylogic

I have 10 agents that will be enter to the node1, and when all the agents are gone I want to have a "stopdelay"
So I want to verify if my node is empty each time to activate the option "stopdelay".

I tried this command "if( self.size() == 0 ) delay.stopDelayForAll();" and "if( queue.contain.count() == 0 ) delay19.stopDelayForAll();" but they ddidn't work as I wanted.

[image: this is a part of my programm]

Comment: where did you write the code, what problems do you get?